# How can you scan QR code using HTML5 and MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, html, c#-4.0, qr-code

Can anyone help or explain how QR code would work using HTML5 and MVC3?

Can it be scanned using laptop webcam or will only work on mobile sit?

Comment: QR code is just a picture... anything that can take a picture can see a QR code. HTML5 has no 'camera' capabilities. that's not what it's for.

Comment: You can ajax the QR code with more buzzwords. Seriously though, use an `<a>` element. That's all QR codes are designed as, ugly anchors on paper.

Comment: So can you scan QR code using HTML5 using MVC3 or not? Do you know any example up there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public camera API in HTML5 as is in a web browser.

For now, you can use frameworks embedding HTML5 to native apps to do this.

An example:

http://phonegap.org

ZBar QR code scanner for Phonegap

http://blog.infoentropy.com/Use_ZBar_barcode_reader_with_PhoneGap

The payload of QR code can be any text, but it is usually a HTML link.

Comment: Thanks Mikko for the reply. Can you allobrate this sentence, because i didn't get it: "no public camera API in HTML5 as it is in the web browser"? Besides allowing it to the native camera, can this be done from a laptop where it has a webcam?

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I would say getUserMedia is pretty close to a "camera API", no?

Comment: That's correct. Please note that the answer was written more than one year ago.

Comment: @Agustin the `getUserMedia ` can be use as a searching for data after scanner a QR?. I am a project that can generate a QR so I need to scan it and find the data from my system(grid)

Answer (score 1):

On Android and iPhone you can scan from a web page this way:
http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningFromWebPages

It's not really scanning with HTML5 or anything, but, may be the closest you can get.

Answer (score 0):

See this https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode
An HTML5 QRCode reader